# How do I alternate the sign of a summation series

Tags: c

I am trying to code the summation of the following series:

[image]

I can't figure out how to alternate the sign from "-" to "+" to "-" and so on....

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=1,n;
    float sum,num,den;
    den=2;
    sum=0;

    printf("Enter number of terms for summation: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        num=i*(i+1);
        den=den*(i+2);
        sum+=num/den;
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
}
```

Comment: `sum+=pow(-1,i)*num/den` is one option

Comment: Add `if ((i & 1) == 0) num = -num;` ??? Or, `if (i & 1) sum += num/den; else sum -= num/den;`

Comment: that is an overkilll

Comment: Use a `int sign = 1;` to also multiply each term by. At the end of the loop, `sign = -sign;`.

Comment: No need to have another variable, `den=-2; ... den=-den*(i+2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a variable at 1.

```
int coeff = +1;
```

then:

```
sum += coeff * num/den;
coeff *= -1;  // Toggles -1 to +1 and back to -1 each loop.
```

When `coeff` is +1, then the expression is `+1 * -1`, which results in `-1`.

When `coeff` is -1, then the expression is `-1 * -1`, which results in `+1`.

the variable keeps toggling back-n-forth between `+1` and `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s discuss the methods proposed in comments and other answers in descending order of nominal burden. (By “nominal burden,” I meant what the code literally says to calculate, disregarding potential compiler optimization.)

- `sum+=pow(-1,i)*num/den`. This calls `pow`, which is a complicated routine. This solution involves a function call and branching through the various special cases that `pow` must handle.
- `if ((i & 1) == 0) num = -num;`. This involves testing, comparing, branching, negating, and assignment. For hardware design reasons, branching may impair performance.
- `int coeff = +1;`, `sum += coeff * num/den;`, and `coeff *= -1;`. Okay, now we are on track. We have added just one variable and two multiplications. The latter does not even have to be a multiplication; it could be just `coeff = -coeff;`.

Having learned from those, can we solve it any more simply? Yes, we make a simple change, from:

`den=den*(i+2);`

to:

`den=-den*(i+2);`

Then `den` will flip between positive and negative each iteration, with just a single negation. However, we do need to start `den` with a negative value; `den = -2;`.

But then, consider this:

`den = den*(-2-i);`

Although this involves more characters changed in the source code, it might not be any more work. `i+2` may be calculated by taking 2 and adding `i`, whereas `-2-i` may be calculated by taking −2 and subtracting `i`, the same amount of work.

Thus, you can make your program work for alternating signs without any more nominal work than the unchanging sign version.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int i=1,n, sign = 1;
    float sum,num,den;
    den=2;
    sum=0;

    printf("Enter number of terms for summation: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        num=i*(i+1);
        den=den*(i+2);
        sum+=sign * num/den;
        sign *= -1;
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `x = i % 2` alternating between 0 and 1, you have two equations in two variables:

```
+1 = A * 0 + B
-1 = A * 1 + B
```

From which you can quickly infer:

```
B = 1
A = -2
```

So what you can do is:

```
    const int A = -2;
    const int B = 1;
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = i % 2;
        int y = A * x + B;
        ...
        sum+=y*num/den;
    }
```